# How change password field to access_token in jwt laravel?

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5.3

I am developing rest API in laravel using jwt. API supporting normal login as well as social network logins such as facebook and google.

In the case of facebook login,Where should I store access token?

If I stored access toeken as separate field,How can I do jwt authentication check,becuase it support email and password field only as follows,

```
$credentials = $request->only('name', 'password');
```

Is it right method to store access token in password fields itself?

Please help to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I always store the access token in its own field in the database.

Then to login, I have a separate script for each type of login (Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc.) that can return a JWT and I simply use that JWT from then on to authenticate for each subsequent API request.

I've really enjoyed using the [Dingo Api](https://github.com/dingo/api) package for my APIs because it groups together some of the best practices for APIs.

Comment: It looks like there were some issues with using it in Laravel 5.3, but those are getting worked out. I'm sorry I don't have personal experience using Dingo with Laravel 5.3. The last project I did with Dingo was with Laravel 5.2.